# What is a half-managed VPN?

Tags: vpn

Our network team has been using the term "half managed VPN."  Is this an industry standard term, and what does it mean?

Comment: Weird.  I've never heard of it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't industry-standard. But I'd hazard a guess that it's a VPN managed by you and a partner - you are responsible for it up to the endpoint on your side and the partner up to their endpoint. It can be frustrating to troubleshoot these based on how free your partner is with information. I've had to practically bludgeon configurations out of partners in the past out of some misguided sense of information security on their part.